# Проблема после перевода в UTF-8 кодировку.

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, php, mysql

Всем привет. Перевел сайт с CP-1251 на UTF-8, но как всегда без проблем не обошлось. Кодировка отображается правильно и в базу заносится кириллица отлично, но регулярные выражения подводят. Во-первых, придется переписывать все регулярные выражения, так как они отличаются от CP-1251 и работают по-другому. А проблема в следующем:

```
<? print preg_replace('/#([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+)/','<a href="/user?search=#$1">#$1</a>',  $msg);?>
```

С CP-1251 работало нормально, но после перевода появилась проблема. Смысл php строки заключается в том, что если в комментарии присутствует @имя, то преобразовывать в ссылку. Но теперь если ввести:

```
#тестовый
```

то появится:

```
#��естовый
```

И как ссылка считается до первого символа вопроса.

Если ввести так:

```
#Окей
```

То выводится нормально и полностью как ссылка.

Так же пробовал вот такие слова и выводится так: #Коне��но, #Н��жно, #Да, #Так, #Пойде��

**Изменено:**
   Заметил, что если убрать теги ссылки из шаблона, то отображается правильно:

```
<? print preg_replace('/#([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+)/','#$1',  $msg);?>
```

Как решить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.
P.S. Проверил в базе слова. Они отображаются в нормальной кириллице.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Модификатор u, может быть?

```
<? print preg_replace('/#([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+)/u','<a href="/user?search=#$1">#$1</a>',  $msg);?>
```

Comment: Гений! =) Спасибо! =)

Comment: @Nick весьма польщён. Но увы, гений не я, а http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

После соединения с базой выполнить

```
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

+сами страницы сохранить в `UTF-8` без `BOM`. Должно сработать.

P.S. Не забыть прописать это

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

В начале каждой страницы.

Comment: alex_90, Вы меня плохо поняли. Кодировка везде прописана правильно: в файлах, в мета, в .htaccess, в базе данных и даже header(); - текст отображается нормально, а вот при использование регулярных выражений появляются через раз кракозябры.

Comment: Тогда не знаю что может быть...

Comment: Проблема, собственно, в регулярных выражениях. Но как решить проблему.