# Проблемы с кодировкой preg_replace()

Tags: php

Просто в файле (без БД и прочего):

```
preg_replace('/[^А-Я,а-я]/', '', "Привет");
```

Получается `П�иве�`.

Comment: .htaccess создай и добавь туда кодировку

Comment: кодировка самого файла на чем? utf-8?

Comment: /[^сca-z0-9а-я!]*/
upd. /[^\p{L}0-9\!]/iu вот так попробуй

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev а есть ли такая пара кодировок, из-за которых только `р` и `т` накрылись бы?

Comment: в htaccess не помагает, да utf-8

Comment: @Aslan Kussein, работает второй вариант, а по-другому нельзя никак?

Comment: @emtecif, что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/86352/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-utf-8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: preg_replace('/[^А-Я,а-я]/u', '', "Привет"); - вот так отлично работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас файл в кодировке utf-8, то в регулярное выражение нужно добавить модификатор u и можно добавить i чтобы игнорировать регистр букв.

```
preg_replace('/[^а-я]/ui', '', "Привет");
```

Comment: А за что `+` ставите? :) Вопрос не верен, как и ответ.

Comment: Мне еще нужно чтобы строка не заканчивалась -, т.е. если в конце строки есть символ - его нужно просто убрать, такое можно сделать?

Comment: Сделать можно всё, только я не понял что именно нужно. В данном примере вы удаляете все символы, которые не входят в алфавит русского языка из строки.